# Only join two columns when it is not null in one table oracle

Tags: oracle, join, null

I have a table a

```
ID | Name | City
1  |Jack  | Null
2  |Tom   | Null
```

And table b

```
ID | Name | City
1  |Jack  | Dever
2  |Tom   | Dallas
```

I need to write a query to join these two tables by id, name and city if they are not null in table a. But any of these three column could be null for each row.

I wrote one below but the performance is bad when data grows

```
Select * from a, b 
Where (a.id is not null and a.id=b.id or a.id is null) and
(a.name is not null and a.name=b.name or a.name is null) and
(a.city is not null and a.city=b.city or a.city is null)
```

Basically, I need to join on the column when it is not null in table a.
Could you shed some light on this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you not using any join condition? If you don't then you will get cartesian product. So if table `A` has 100 rows and table `B` has 100 rows, you will get `100*100 = 10000` rows without any where clause. Do you really want to do this and are you getting expected result by the query you gave?

Comment: I think this query is the same as join condition, isn't it? My expectation is not Cartesian , just join. Or I can use the following query Select * from a join b 
On (a.id is not null and a.id=b.id or a.id is null) and
(a.name is not null and a.name=b.name or a.name is null) and
(a.city is not null and a.city=b.city or a.city is null)

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding it properly, but please add some more example data in tables and then give your expected output based on that. Use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to create it and share the link so we can see that you did.

Comment: The expression `a.id is not null and a.id=b.id` is the same as `a.id = b.id` because the `=` operator will not compare null values anyway. The `a.id is null` seems to to indicate you want an outer join. What is the expected output based on your sample data. And please add example rows with `a.id = null` and show what the result for those should be.

Comment: Basically I don't want to join with the column when the entire column is null in table a

Comment: I don't understand the sense of this select but as far as you explained, this select should work: `Select * from a, b where (a.id is not null or a.name is not null or a.city is not null) and nvl(a.id, b.id) = b.id and nvl(a.name, b.name) = b.name and nvl(a.city, b.city) = b.city`. Could you please explain, what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try this one to test the performance

Comment: I tried this method, however it is extremely slow....Do you have any idea to improve the speed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ATTEMPT I:
Would this be what you need? It seems to do what I can read out from your question.

```
with a as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, null    city from dual
            union all
            select 2 id, 'Tom'  name, null    city from dual
            union all
            select 3 id, 'Mike' name, 'Miami'   city from dual)
     ,b as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, 'Dever'  city from dual
            union all
            select 2 id, 'Tom'  name, 'Dallas' city from dual
            union all
            select 3 id, 'Mike' name, 'Boise'   city from dual)
select b.* 
  from b
  left outer join a
    on a.id   = b.id
   and a.name = b.name
 where b.city  = nvl(a.city, b.city);
```

If not, please advisa as to what would need to change in the result or possibly in the indata.

UPDATE I:
To allow all columns to have the possibility of being null, this could be one way of doing it. I've added testdata for the conditions I think your are describing. It gives the result I think you are looking for.

```
with a as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, null    city from dual
            union all
            select 2 id, 'Tom'  name, null    city from dual
            union all
            select 3 id, 'Mike' name, 'Miami'   city from dual
            union all
            select 4 id, 'Don' name, null   city from dual
            union all
            select 5 id, null name, 'London'   city from dual
            union all
            select null id, 'Erin' name, 'Berlin'   city from dual
           )
     ,b as (select 1 id, 'Jack' name, 'Dever'  city from dual
            union all
            select 2 id, 'Tom'  name, 'Dallas' city from dual
            union all
            select 3 id, 'Mike' name, 'Boise'   city from dual
            union all
            select 4 id, 'Don' name, 'Dover'   city from dual
            union all
            select 5 id, 'Lis' name, 'London'   city from dual
            union all
            select 6 id, 'Erin' name, 'Berlin'   city from dual
           )
select b.*, a.* 
  from b
  inner join a
    on b.id   = nvl(a.id,   b.id) 
   and b.name = nvl(a.name, b.name)
   and b.city = nvl(a.city, b.city)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however, any of three entire columns could be null, so I need to have a dynamic join query on column when they are not null. Ps, column will be null for each row or not null for each row